# selectionStart of textarea returns wrong value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textarea with onfocus event. I want to find out the line number on which the cursor is when the user clicks on it.

Here's what I have in the onfocus event:

```
function onFocusFunction(){
    var lineNr = $('#textAreaId').val().substr(0, $('#textAreaId')[0].selectionStart).split("\n").length;
}
```

Here's the problem:

My text area is empty, it has four lines, so it contains this: \n\n\n\n

The first time onFocusFunction is called, $('#textAreaId')[0].selectionStart returns 1, no matter which line was clicked. After that it works great. What's causing this and is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Which browser? http://jsfiddle.net/rwcR6/1/ it works fine in ff

Comment: @abc667 Fiddle also doesn't work, I always get 1.

Comment: It seems that it's a bug in chrome. If you use other event than `onFocus` (for e.g. `onClick`) it return right value.